# How do format output text to show only whole numbers and not decimals along with it in Vf page

Tags: salesforce, visualforce

I want to display a field in a object to show just the whole number/integer value. This field has decimal values in the structure but for i need to show the integer value for this VF page only.

```
 <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
                    <apex:outputLabel value="# Connections" for="Connections"/>
                    <apex:outputText id="Connections" value="{!Event__c.Total_Connections__c}" />         
                </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
```

No of connections has to be shown as whole number.

thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use parametrized output with formating, for example:

```
<apex:outputText id="Connections" value="{0, number, integer}">
    <apex:param value="{!Event__c.Total_Connections__c}" />
</apex:outputText>
```

For more detail about all the formating options, check [Java's MessageFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/MessageFormat.html), the same formating is used for `<apex:outputText>`

Comment: You can also cheat for this particular case, and just do `value="{!FLOOR(MyVar)}"' — nice and easy way of getting rid of that pesky decimal!

Comment: any idea how to get this to work in site.com? When I do an output in a Data Element, I'm always getting the decimal value. I was hoping to use this, "{!FLOOR(MyVar)}", but site.com doesn't recognize the FLOOR function.